# Finding Bevel Angle

Tags: geometry, matlab

I need to find the bevel angle of a "box" with 4, 5, 6 or 8 sides.  The shape is tilting outward at 10 and 20 degrees. All sides are the same length, and the bevel angle should be the same for each. How would I go about computing this?

Assuming the tilt angle looks something like this:
http://jansson.us/planterboxes.jpg
Would the tilt angle effect the bevel angle of the box?

My first idea is that since it is box with an overall shape with a standard side length, I could simply solve with a simple equation like this:

360 degrees/number of sides

Would this method work?

Comment: Could you clarify what is means to be "tilting outward"? For example, which part of the shape with four sides that are tilting outward?

Comment: I was given very little information but I am assuming it means something similar to this: http://jansson.us/planterboxes.jpg

Comment: Please provide more description in the post, including your own guesses, otherwise the readers will only have less clue than you do. The graphics are certainly important. However, at this point, your problem is under-determined. The bevel angle is totally not restricted by the number of sides or the tilting angle. You need more constraints.

Comment: "Bevel" could be any of a number of things. Can you describe more precisely which of the many possible angles in the parts of the assembly you want to measure? Do you want to cut miter angles in all the edges of the pieces? The edges between the sides in your photo seem mitered, but it's hard to tell how the bottom is attached.

Answer (score 1):

The tilt and bevel angle values are the same for a thick rectangular central cross section of planter wall. We can choose either bevel $ {  10^ {\circ}}$ or bevel $ {20^{\circ}}$ ( Angle between horizontal plane and slant face normal) and we have $8$ combinations for polygon frustums $ (p,4,8),$ among which you don't want $(p=7).$

We could have a common base inner circle diameter 1 meter  for a set of planter boxes. Image for  planter box  $  (bevel\,20^{\circ} , p=8 )$ is given:

[image]

Top and bottom regular polygons have equal side lengths inside circum diameters $D_1,D_2$ with slant lengths $L,$ so bevel angle can be found from:

$$ \sin(bevel\, angle) =\dfrac{(D_2-D_1) }{2L} $$